# Почему не видит функцию?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, concept

1. Можете объяснить почему в методе run std::bind не видет void write(std::string && msg)?
2. как можно изменить код (не меняя интерфейс класса), чтобы решить эту проблему?
3. есть ли пример концепта для метода run? я имею ввиду концепт, который будет проверять что Func и переменное кол-во аргументов - исполняемый объект?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
struct Foo {
    void add(std::string && msg) {
        run(&Foo::write, this, std::move(msg));
    }
    template<class Func, class ...Args>
    void run(Func && func, Args && ... args) {
        auto task = std::bind(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        task();
    }
    void write(std::string && msg) {
        std::cout << "Foo::write " << msg << '\n';
    }
};
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.add("hello!");
    return 0;
}
```

upd
сама ошибка

```
main.cpp:18:13: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::_Bind))(std::basic_string&&)>) ()’
         task();
         ~~~~^~
In file included from main.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:547:2: note: candidate: template _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (Foo::*)(std::basic_string&&); _Bound_args = {Foo*, std::basic_string, std::allocator >}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args)
```

Comment: *"в методе run не видна"* - она там видна. Задавайте по одному вопросу за раз.

Comment: Ошибку компиляции для (1) хорошо бы добавить.

Comment: Может у вас на самом деле вопрос про то, как избавиться от ошибки компиляции в этом примере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто исправьте функцию `write` на такую

```
void write(const std::string& msg) {
    std::cout << "Foo::write " << msg << '\n';
}
```

ну не знает `bind` о том, что нужно Ваш аргумент передавать таким способом. и не находит подходящей перегрузки

> Можете объяснить почему в методе run std::bind не видет void write(std::string && msg)?

Потому что bind на самом деле создает функциональный объект (грубо говоря класс, где переданные параметры - переменные этого класса. А они по определению не будут rvalue).

> как можно изменить код (не меняя интерфейс класса), чтобы решить эту проблему?

В вопросе немного не видно, где интерфейс класса, а где нет. Но если где то не работает bind, то нужно использовать лямбды. Маерс в своей книге утверждает, что есть только один случай, где bind ему кажется красивее.

В процессе экспериментов, родился вот такой **франкинштейн** (поэтому не ругайте:) ). Насколько он "не нарушает интерфейсов", я не знаю. Но он компилируется и работает.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Foo {

    void add(std::string && msg) {
        run([&](std::string&&s) {this->write(std::move(s));}, std::move(msg));
    }
    template<class Func, class ...Args>
    void run(Func func, Args && ... args) {
        auto task = [&]() { func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };
        task();
    }
    void write(std::string&& msg) {
        std::cout << "Foo::write " << msg << '\n';
    }
};
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.add("hello!");
    return 0;
}
```

> есть ли пример концепта для метода run? я имею ввиду концепт, который будет проверять что Func и переменное кол-во аргументов - исполняемый объект?

я не думаю, что они Вам нужны.

Comment: да что ж такое с этими минусаторами. пришел, минуснул, возрадовался! день удался

Comment: спасибо, но решение мне известно :)
вопрос как можно без изменения интерфейса решить проблему и главное понять почему так отрабатывает.

Comment: ОП задал аж 3 вопроса, причем первые два из них невалидные, так как описываемая в них проблема не существует. А тут, не отвечая ни на один из них, предлагается менять интерфейс класса, что судя по записи *"(не меняя интерфейс класса)"*, не нужно.

Comment: я чуточку обновил ответ